# When I refresh the page, my to-do list disappears

Tags: web, refresh

I am trying to make a to-do list but when I **refresh** the page, all the elements that I added before in the to-do list disappears and the to-do list seems the same as it was initially.

How can I add such functionality that I can save my added elements permanently in my to-do list?

Comment: What language are you using? Javascript? You must be specific when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

## localStorage

If you are using JavaScript, then instead of using plain variables, **you can use localStorage**.

---

**localStorage will last until the cache is cleared in the browser. Meaning that it will last for a long time on the majority of browsers.**

**To set a "variable": `localStorage.setItem('nameofvar','valueyouaresetting')`;


To use the "variable": `localStorage.getItem('myvar')`;**

He an short example of using them:

```
function(user_input){
  localStorage.setItem('choice',user_input)
  myFunction()
}
function myFunction(){
  if(localStorage.getItem('choice') == 'apple'){
    alert("You chose apple");
  } else{
    alert("You did not chose apple");
  }
}
```

Hope that helps, you can also use localSession if you wish the data to be destroyed when the user closes their browser.

Here are some resources where you can learn about them:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage